# Is there an assembly id property in a Maven assembly?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I would like to use the assembly id as a property in a component xml file rather than duplicating a section of across multiple assemblies. Looking through the maven-assembly-plugin documentation I cannot see any reference to an assembly id. Any ideas if it is available?

Here is an example of what I would like to add to a component xml file.

```
<files>
    <file>
        <source>src/main/config/${assembly.id}.properties</source>
        <destName>/conf/config.properties</destName>
    </file>
</files>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use maven filtering for that:

1. Define the `${assembly.id}` property in the POM
2. Configure the folder which contains the assembly descriptor(s) as resource folder and enable filtering on this folder
3. Use `${assembly.id}` as `<id>` in your assembly descriptor and your component descriptor
4. configure the maven-assembly-plugin to use the (filtered) assembly descriptor from the `target` directory.